# How to remove untagged images after build?

Tags: docker

First of all, I have googled a lot and suggestions like `docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc` does not work for me. And I have removed all containers as well, `docker ps -a` now shows nothing.

What I have done is after building a new image via `docker build -t frederickzh/some-image .`, the tag is then assigned to the new image, leaving the old one with `<none>`, e.g.:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
frederickzh/some-image   latest              064afd1e1f42        31 seconds ago      1.86GB
frederickzh/some-image   <none>              c59371df7b4a        About an hour ago   1.86GB
```

But then if I run `docker rmi c59371df7b4a`, there will be an error:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete c59371df7b4a (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

What I want to do now is to remove the untagged entry from image list, but certainly leaving the latest build untouched.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Because the new `Dockerfile` has simply several new lines at the end, actually the new image is a child of the old one. Hence `prune` commands do not work in my case.

Comment: is the image running ? `docker ps -a` try cleaning exited containers and see if that helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani I said `docker ps -a` showed nothing...

Comment: Sorry missed reading that. Can you try `docker system prune -f` and see if that works?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Neither `system prune` nor `image prune` works ;(

Comment: Then only thing i can say is cleanup the setup and try again. Stop docker and then `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` and start stocker. If the problem persists then probably a docker bug